# node embed databases with faster search speed

Tags: sql, node.js, database, nosql

Actually im using SQlite to store some list of "files" with some attributes, no relational data only one file with multiple data, so i think any relational or nosql DB is valid for me.
The problem right now is the Speed of the searchs, I need to embed the db using Node and storing a file in the project folder, actually im using node sqlite3, but i tested yerterday the better-sqlite3 module to, and the results are similar.

My table structure is like this:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════╦════════════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ id ║     hash     ║   name   ║   description  ║   date  ║      tags     ║    languages     ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════╣════════════════╣═════════╣═══════════════╣══════════════════╣
║INT ║     TEXT     ║   TEXT   ║     TEXT       ║  NUMBER ║     JSON      ║       JSON       ║
║  2 ║ b2b22b2b2bb2 ║ two test ║  lorem ipsum b ║ 1233123 ║ ["d","e","f"] ║ ["ko","en","tk"] ║
║  3 ║ asdasdasdsad ║ 333 test ║  lorem ipsum c ║ 1233123 ║ ["a","d","c"] ║ ["es","de","fr"] ║
║  4 ║ 4s342s423424 ║ 444 test ║  lorem ipsum d ║ 1233123 ║ ["a","b","g"] ║ ["es","pt","fr"] ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════╩════════════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

The results with arround 300.000 rows are:

`Select * from files WHERE name LIKE "%string%"` : 300ms

`select * from files WHERE (tags LIKE '"music"' OR tags LIKE '"banana"') AND (languages LIKE '"esp"' OR languages LIKE '"ger"')` : 400ms

`select id from files` : 130ms (try with "select count(id) as counter FROM files", its slower that make this and count the results arround 30ms vs 150ms)

The results are not bad... but here is only one search operation, and my program allow multiple users search at same time, so the search times become unaceptable. (10 clients, ~4 seconds per reply)
Im running the test in a Core i7 4820K, with 500Gb SSD (550R/450W) move to the HDD RAID0 increase a lot the query times

I try to create indexx per every search column, the inserts in this project are ocassional so i dont care to much about the insert speed, but is weird because put an index in the name, tags or languages fields not improbe to much the speed (arround 50ms only, but increase the table size a lot obviously)

So.. im looking alternatives, i need a node embed DB with extreme search speed and no DB locking (i think with time the DB can grow to 2M rows), but without consume enormous quantity of memory, dont care about if is relational or not.

EDIT: Im making many many tests and here are my results:

For node-lmdb the creation speed is insanelly fast, like work with memcache, arroung 100.000 inserts in 4 seconds, and read the data is working good, but because is a key-value Database I need to transform the given data in JSON and then make the "search" logic, and this decrease the results a lot, here is a example code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const lmdb = require('node-lmdb')

const env = new lmdb.Env()

env.open({
    path: __dirname + "/mydata",
    mapSize: 2*1024*1024*1024, // maximum database size 
    maxDbs: 3
})

var dbi = env.openDbi({
    name: "myPrettyDatabase",
    create: true // will create if database did not exist 
})

// Begin transaction
var txn = env.beginTxn()

let t0 = new Date().getTime()


// Create cursor
let cursor = new lmdb.Cursor(txn, dbi)
let counter = 0
let find = 0

for (var found = cursor.goToFirst(); found !== null; found = 
cursor.goToNext()) {
    cursor.getCurrentString(function(key, data) {

        let js
        try {
            js = JSON.parse(data)
            counter++
        } catch (e) { js = null }

        if (js && String(js.name).indexOf('Lorem') !== -1) {
            find++
        }
    })
}

console.log('counter: ' + counter)
console.log('find: ' + find)

// Close cursor
cursor.close();


let t1 = new Date().getTime()
console.log('time: ' + (t1-t0))


// Commit transaction
txn.commit()

dbi.close()
```

The results are:

$ node index.js
counter: 215548
find: 113073
time: 1516

The list speed is arround 200ms but the JSON conversion and the litle "search" logic slow down under sqlite speed (or im doing something wrong)

I do other experiments with Tingodb, that is a embed DB but with a system like MongoDB, I insert 200K object like this:

```
{ hash: '3736b5da857a4c7b9b046f326004803a',
  name: 'inia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem I',
  description: ', looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of ',
  tags: [ 'pc', 'pc', 'hd', 'mp4' ],
  languages: [ 'fre', 'jap', 'deu' ] }
```

The insertions was incredible, arround 100K in 2 ces, but... here is the experiment:

```
const Db = require('tingodb')({cacheSize: 60000, cacheMaxObjSize: 4096}).Db
const assert = require('assert')
const crypto = require('crypto')
var db = new Db('./', {})

// Fetch a collection to insert document into 
var collection = db.collection("batch_document_insert_collection_safe")

let t0 = new Date().getTime()
collection.find({ tags: 'video' }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(err)  
    console.log(docs)  
    let t1 = new Date().getTime()
    console.log('time: ' + (t1-t0))
})
```

Running this in the 200K DB cost a total of 38 SECONDSs dont know if is normal or not...

And about aladb, I test it and work well, I make another experiments (right now i dont have) and the performance is good and is similar to sqlite3 with some nice things, but is in some searchs is like 2x slower than sqlite (using LIKE %string% kill the engine).

EDIT 2: after many research and tests using ab command (ab -n 10000 -c 50 http://machine.tst:13375/library/search?tags=lorem) in linux machine to simulate multiple request, I finally keep using the sqlite3 library but creating one aditional table at start (memory one) and storing the request responses processed in the table (`id(INT), hash(VARCHAR), object(TEXT), last(NUMBER)`).

The first time I use the request data to create a unique hash ("GET" + "/a/b/c" + JSON(requestData)) and json encode the response, now the first time the query continue return at normal speed, but the next one is like use memcache or similar DB, and now I get from 10 request/s to ~450 request/s with 10% CPU usage.

Anyway I do a watcher event that check the "last" column of the cached lines to remove old request and preven memory problems, I check that only one request have the params changed multiple times, all other request are the same always, so i think the memory usage dont grow to much.

If in the future if I found some better embed options than the sqlite3 I try and change the DB engine

Comment: how about `AlaSQL` (https://github.com/agershun/alasql) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [LMDB](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/) with [Node-LMDB](https://github.com/Venemo/node-lmdb)

The performance is quite good and for your use case it looks to be an ideal one. I could achieve 1,000,000 rows/sec per client.